# Make two divs occupy the remaining height

Tags: html, css

I want to make two columns occupy the remaning space. I don't know what to do anymore, both divs have the same properties, yet when I set the top CSS property for the "sidebar" div it goes down, when I set it for the "content" div it goes up.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
  top: 153px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10000px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>

  <div id="content">
    <section>
      content
    </section>
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the result

[image: my result]

I am so confused, I don't understand what's happening in there anymore. The green line is the navigation bar and the space between the nav bar and the top of the page is because of a logo (hidden by the yellow block)

Comment: Can you be more precise ? Occupy which remaining space ? A jsFiddle would be appreciated.

Comment: ocuppy all the space between the navbar and the bottom of the page (where the footer is)

Comment: can you provide a picture of your desired output?

Comment: You should consider using the `flexbox` model.

Comment: Show desired output. Link a fiddle. Is the green box your `<header>`? Because that will affect the answer. We need more information.

Comment: give the wrapper height of 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top:50px;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, thanks to you, I finally understood position:absolute!! ^_^

Comment: Nice! I'm glad I could help!